# Access and modify an in-memory variable from Next.js API routes

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a couple API routes and I want to get and modify an object that I defined in another file.

Is this posible?

For example,

In `inMemoryDB.js` I defined the variable:

```
export const test = {
    ['key1']: {
      id: '...',
      name: 'jane'
   }
}
```

Then in `pages/api`:

- In endpoint 1, I read `test`, and modify it `test['key1'].name = 'john'`.
- In endpoint 2, when I read `test['key1'].name` it still says 'jane'.

Code:

`inMemoryDB.ts`

```
export const testDB = {
  ['key1']: {
    id: 'key1',
    name: 'jane'
  }
};
```

pages/api/in-memory-test/endpoint1.ts

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

import { testDB } from '../../../src/constants/inMemoryDB';

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  switch (req.method) {
    case 'GET':
      return getEndpoint1(req, res);

    default:
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: 'Bad request'
      });
  }
}

const getEndpoint1 = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  console.log('[testDB - 1]', testDB);

  testDB['key1'].name = 'john';

  return res.status(200).json({ testDB });
};
```

pages/api/in-memory-test/endpoint2.ts

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { testDB } from '../../../src/constants/inMemoryDB';

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  switch (req.method) {
    case 'POST':
      return postEndpoint2(req, res);

    default:
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: 'Bad request'
      });
  }
}

const postEndpoint2 = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  return res.status(200).json({ testDB });
};
```

When I do GET request to endpoint1:

```
{
    "testDB": {
        "key1": {
            "id": "key1",
            "name": "john"
        }
    }
}
```

And then testDB['key1'].name change to 'john' seems to persist in this endpoint.

But when later I do POST request to endpoint2:

```
{
    "testDB": {
        "key1": {
            "id": "key1",
            "name": "jane"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you have made a copy of the variable somehow which does not get updated, this should not be happening. Please share your code

Comment: @TusharShahi I added some code if that helps :)